# IE9/10 accessibility keyboard navigation issue

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, accessibility, internet-explorer-10

Hi I'm having an issue on an app HTML5/JavaScript (sproutcore) I'm working on where pressing the tab key navigates through the links on the page. In IE 9/10 once all the links have been passed the and the focus reaches the address bar and becomes stuck there while in other browsers the cycle starts again at the first link as expected.

I open the app in a popup window via the javascript in a link such as below

```
onclick="window.open('https://myappurl:4020','myApp','location=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,titlebar=yes,toolbar=no').focus();"
```

I have noticed when setting toolbar=yes this issue no longer occurs.

Anyone else seen this issue before as I'm stuck wondering what could be causing this.

Thanks Tobias

Comment: can you post some code from the app? Are you using tabindex by mistake?

Comment: Can't post any code its from a huge app so would know where to start. Also company policy doesn't allow me to post it.

There are no tagindex attributes at all I let the browser decide what order to navigate links itself. I tried setting tab indexes to the links but no success.